# How Proxifier works?

Tags: networking, proxy, ip, socks, torrent

How does proxifier works ?

Eg- My college doesn't allow students to connect to torrent sites.But when we put a specific i.p address in proxifier and set the "protocol type" to HTTPS in proxifier, torrent sites open.How does it happen.Just this one specific ip(172.16.1.11) works,nothing else.What is so special with this ip.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are able to access disallowed torrent sites because you are viewing them through a proxy server. And this specific ip (172.16.1.11) is probably pointing to a proxy server inside your college that uses HTTPS protocal and is not banned from visiting those sites. When you first added that proxy server to Proxifier, There will be a message box asking you "Do you want Proxifier to use this proxy by default? You can change this later at Profile->Proxification_Rules". And if you click "Yes" here(I guess you did), the software will set this server to be your default proxy server.

Now open the Proxification Rules windows, you will see preferences like this:

```
Rule Name   Applications    Target Hosts       Target Ports        Action
Localhost       Any      localhost; 127.0.0.1;      Any            Direct
                            %ComputerName%
Default         Any               Any               Any          Proxy HTTPS 
                                                                 172.16.1.11
```

And this means all your none-local traffic will be sent to that server, and when using a proxy server, whether you can access a web resource or not is determined by that server. I believe you will find more information on this question by asking "What is a proxy server and how does it work?". Try to search on Google, Good luck.